# Replace csv column with for loop in python

Tags: python, pandas, nltk

I'm trying to replace my dataset with some different way. I know below code blocks seems unlogical but I have to do with this way. Is there any option replace my 'Text' values in csv file to my tokenized and filtered lines with for loop ?

```
dataset = pandas.read_csv('/root/Desktop/%20/%1004.csv' , encoding='cp1252')



counter=0


for field in dataset['text']:
    tokens = word_tokenize(field.translate(table))
    tokens2= [w for w in tokens if not w in stop_words]
    tokens3 = [token for token in tokens2 if not all(char.isdigit() or char == '.' or char == '-' for char in token)]
    lemmatized_word = [wordnet_lemmatizer.lemmatize(word) for word in tokens3]
    stemmed_word = [snowball_stemmer.stem(word) for word in lemmatized_word]



    ##### ANY CODE TO REPLACE ITEMS IN dataset['Text'] to stemmed_word
    ##### LIKE ;
    dataset['Text']s first value = stemmed_word[counter]
    counter=counter+1
    then save replaced csv file
```

Comment: missing context in [mre]: `field`, `table`, `stop_words` - we have no clue what they are. Please create a [mre]that we can execute, see the output and describe what your output should be.

Comment: Why not just save the tokenized words as a new file?

Comment: @JethroCao because I have features at another columns like age , gender , experience.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> because I have features at another columns like age , gender ,
>   experience.

You can just leave the data you don't intend to modify as they are, and write them to the new file along with your modified column of lemmatized words. Then whether you write the new processed dataset to a new file or overwrite your old one is entirely up to you. Though I'd personally choose to write to a new file (it's unlikely that adding another CSV file will be a problem to your computer's storage nowadays).

Anyway, to write files, you can use the csv module.

```py
import pandas
import csv

dataset = pandas.read_csv('/root/Desktop/%20/%1004.csv' , encoding='cp1252')

# do your text processing on the desired column for your dataset
# ...
# ...
# ...

dataT = dataset.transpose()

with open('new_dataset', 'wb') as csvfile:
    writer = csv.writer(csvfile)
    for r in dataT:
        writer.writerow(dataT[r])
```

I can't fully test it out, since I don't know the exact format of your dataset. But it should be something along this line (perhaps you should be writing the processed dataframe directly, and not its transpose; you should be able to figure that out yourself after playing around with it).

Comment: df = pandas.DataFrame(data={"text": row})
df.to_csv("./file.csv", sep=',',index=False)

Works too nice approach. Thanks sir.